# How to pass proper url using fetch to asp.net controller?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a bootstrap dropdown with multiple `lis`. and I need to call an action within the controller onClick the `li`.

but I always get this error

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

**lis looks like this**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroup">
    @foreach (var item in Model.tags)
    {
    <li class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <span style="cursor:pointer" class="dropdown-item w-75 itemTag">
            @item.tagName
        </span>
        <i data-deleteUrl="@Url.Action("DeleteTag","EditorSections")?tag=@item.Id" class="bi bi-x-circle-fill w-25 deleteTag"></i>
    </li>
    }
 </ul>
```

I use in the element `i` the dataset `data-deleteUrl` to pass the target url to the controller as follows

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target && e.target.classList.contains('deleteTag')) {
        var getUrl = e.target.dataset["deleteUrl"];
        DeleteTag(getUrl, e.target);
    }

});

function DeleteTag(url, e) {
    fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            if (data == "OK") {
                var li = e.parentNode;
                li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
            }
        });
    return false;
};
```

but as I mentioned, It doesn't access the controller because I always get this error

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

for more details, I provided some images

[image: Source as showen in JS]

[image: Network]

[image: Element inspection]

[image: the controler's delete action]

Note: when I was using inline onClick event it was working but when I started to use eventlistener instead I get the upmentioned error

```
<i onclick="DeleteTag('@Url.Action("DeleteTag","EditorSections")?tag=', this.parentElement)" class="bi bi-x-circle-fill float-end mx-3 deleteTag"></i>
```

Comment: Inspect the actual request made in browser dev tools network tab. Is url as expected? What is in response body?

Comment: @charlietfl with element inspection the url looks good (data-deleteurl="/EditorSections/DeleteTag?tag=b92ccad6-a64f-41e9-9be5-02737e02d358") but in the network tap it gives me 404

Comment: So you need to check `response.ok` before returning `response.json()` and do a `throw` instead if not ok. As for the 404 we have no way to know why that is occurring and you need to debug server side or modify url used

Comment: @charlietfl I add some images for more clarification.

Comment: Looks like extra quotes in the `tag=` part of url in html. Then notice the `undefined` in actual url of the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like part of the problem is using `dataset["deleteUrl"]` to extract from the element.

That implies an attribute `data-delete-url`. Browser will normalize `data-deleteUrl` to lower case.

You need to use `dataset["deleteurl"]` instead. I suggest you keep all your attributes in lowercase also

---

Demonstration:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div')

console.log(div.dataset)
```

```html
<div data-deleteUrl="foo" data-delete-url="bar">Some content</div>
```

Comment: thanks @charlietfl it's true using data-deleteUrl returns undefined, however using data-deleteurl instead returns with the correct url.